# For each element in vector, how many elements to the right of the particular element are less than? (without using a loop)

Tags: r, stat

Say that I have the following vector """ 3 1 5 7 9 """.

Say for element 3, this would be 1, while for element 1, this would be 0.

How can I do this for each element without using a for loop?

What if I am given a matrix, and I need to do this for each row?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `outer`, `upper.tri` and `colSums`.

```
x <- c(3,1,5,7,9)
. <- outer(x, x, `-`)
.[upper.tri(.)] <- 0
colSums(. < 0)
#[1] 1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I would never thought of that. Any tips to improve my R programming skills for later on?